# Github Service Hooks: auto config pre-built integrations information

Tags: java, github, github-api

Under Github Hooks and services, there are some pre-build integrations, which we need to fill-in info such as server url, username, password. Is there a way I can use API to auto fill-in instead of add all this information under each repo. 
For example, for Jira and Bugzilla, they are prebuild, both require Server url, Username,Password etc. Instead of setup all my repos, use a java code to direct send though API. But not sure where I should start.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub got pre define list, [This page](https://api.github.com/hooks) gives details on how to set up a webhook.